# Google Maps through proxy server with NGINX

Tags: google-maps, nginx, google-maps-api-3, proxy, reverse-proxy

I am trying to install an Angular application which uses google maps in a very restricted intranet. I have access to Google Maps through my server (which serves my app using NGINX), but not from my client. So those are the steps I took so far.

1 - I set the server IP for maps.googleapis.com in my /etc/hosts file in the client.

2 - I set the google maps IP in my /etc/hosts file in the server.

3 - I created a conf file so Nginx knows it needs to proxy pass this domain:

```
server{
  listen 80;
  server_name maps.googleapis.com;
  location/ {
    proxy_pass http://216.58.212.10/$uri$is_args$args;
    proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
  }
}
```

I can download the first google maps api request:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=visualization&sensor=false&callback=onGoogleReady
```

But when it tries to download this one:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/ViewportInfoService.GetViewportInfo?1m6&1m2&1d38.48493576049805&2d-9.36532974243164&2m2&1d38.97382736206055&2d-8.891716003417969&2u12&4sen-US&5e0&6sm%40366000000&7b0&8e0&callback=_xdc_._kxuspe&token=52829
```

It shows me this error:

```
The Google Maps Javascript must be downloaded directly from Google's servers.
```

Am I missing something here? Did anybody do that before? An more importantly: is it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible or not, but your [error](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#errorcodes) that you received `"The Google Maps JavaScript API must be downloaded directly from Google's servers."` means that the script element that loads the Google Maps JavaScript API is not being included correctly on your page. In order for the API to work correctly, it must be loaded directly from `https://maps.googleapis.com`. For more information, check this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API)